# Is there any way to upload doc, pdf files through Alamofire?

Tags: ios, file-upload, alamofire, swift4, xcode9

I have gone through many post but couldn't satisfied, currently I'm using `File Explorer Framework` and its working fine, but when I select a file (File can be pdf, docs or any text file), then how would I Upload that file in a server?

```
let fileExplorer = FileExplorerViewController()
fileExplorer.canChooseFiles = true //specify whether user is allowed to choose files
fileExplorer.canChooseDirectories = false //specify whether user is allowed to choose directories
fileExplorer.allowsMultipleSelection = true //specify whether user is allowed to choose multiple files and/or directories
fileExplorer.delegate = self

self.present(fileExplorer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and its delegate method

```
public func fileExplorerViewController(_ controller: FileExplorerViewController, didChooseURLs urls: [URL]) {
    //Your code here
}
```

now how do I upload the file by getting the file url from the delegate method ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try Alamofire form data. You can upload doc, txt , mp3 etc. files.

Comment: @sharadchauhan can you provide my any code snippet, it would help me lot, whatever i found was for all image uploading code.

Answer (score 4):

you can use documentpicker

```
fileprivate func p_documentclicked() { 
    let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text", "public.data","public.pdf", "public.doc"], in: .import) 
    importMenu.delegate = self 
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

and then it has a delegate method

```
internal func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) { 
   let cico = url as URL 
   print(cico) 
   self.downloadfile(URL: cico as NSURL) 
}
```

After having the `URL` you can download file and then upload the file.

```
fileprivate func downloadfile(URL: NSURL) {
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                // Success
                let statusCode = response?.mimeType
                print("Success: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.p_uploadDocument(data!, filename: URL.lastPathComponent!)
                })

                // This is your file-variable:
                // data
            }
            else {
                // Failure
                print("Failure: %@", error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

you can use this method for uploading doc and pdf file :

```
fileprivate func p_uploadDocument(_ file: Data,filename : String) {

        let parameters = ["yourParam" : "sample text"]
        let fileData = file
        let URL2 = try! URLRequest(url: "your api", method: .post, headers: ["Authorization" :"your auth key"])

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

            multipartFormData.append(fileData as Data, withName: "upfile", fileName: filename, mimeType: "text/plain")


            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, with: URL2 , encodingCompletion: { (result) in

            switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    print("s")
                    upload.responseJSON {
                        response in
                        if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any]{
                            let messageString = JSON["message"] as? String
                             // use the JSON
                            }else {
                               //error hanlding
                            }

                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                   // error handling
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: How do u converting your file (.pdf file) into data? I'm using file explorer framework. what r u using to select the file and converting it into data for passing `fileData` parameter ?

Comment: @AbhishekMitra edited the ans for your clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, I need to know, what u have used to pick the pdf file or how do u picking the pdf file?

Comment: yes I will @swetans don't worry, but till it is not solving my problem. I have stuck in converting/ picking the files.

Comment: Can I help in picking the file from iCloud ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159678/discussion-between-abhishek-mitra-and-swetansh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

I used this to upload mp3. And its in objective-c, I hope you can convert it to swift easily.

```
- (void) uploadFileToServer{
    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
                                 // serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

    [manager POST:@"your_url" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:audioData
                                    name:@"audio_file"
                                fileName:@"MyAudioMemo.m4a" mimeType:@"audio/m4a"];

        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[sender dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    name:@"sender"];

        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[receiver dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    name:@"receiver"];

        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[senderLanguage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    name:@"sender_language"];

        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[receiverLanguage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    name:@"receiver_language"];

        // etc.
    } progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {

            NSError *jsonError = nil;
            NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response = %@",str);
            NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)responseObject
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:&jsonError];
            NSLog(@"\nDictionary : %@", JSON);

        }

       // NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
       // NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
            } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];


}
```